# https iframe mobilefirst returning ssl handshake error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

hi is there a way to connect to a https iframe/image from an remote server from an hybrid mobile first 6.3 android app without passing throught the mobile first server?

i have a page with a:

```
<iframe id="resultadosDisp_iframe" src="https://..."></iframe>

<img src="https://...jpg">
```

im getting this in my logcat:

```
[ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(962)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
```

is there a way to put a keystore in the app or the image data must go throught a mobilefirst adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use iFrames in 2015, let alone in mobile apps.

Your can use HTML5 localstorage and/or IBM JSONStore to store a base64 encoded string - that is the image - and decode the string back to an image when needed. Plenty of questions are already available on the subject of base64 encode/decode.

You can read more about JSONStore here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/data/jsonstore/